# jquery - ajaxStop is not consistently executing javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I am using jquery 1.9.1.  I have logout code where I need to post to multiple pages then do a redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    logoutRedirect();
    });
logoutOfApps();
}
</script>
```

These methods are in a different javascript file (but I think that is irrelavent).

```
function logoutOfApps(){
    $.post("/app1/logout");
    $.post("/app2/logout");
}
function logoutRedirect(){
    var redirectOnLogoutURL = null;
    redirectOnLogoutURL = "/mylogoutdisplaypage";
    top.location = redirectOnLogoutURL;
}
```

SECOND TRY: This also doesn't work consistently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    logoutOfApps();
    logoutRedirect();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Textbook race condition! You need to make sure both requests complete before you take the next action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure both requests have finished before you redirect

```
function logoutOfApps(){
    return $.when(
        $.post("/app1/logout"),
        $.post("/app2/logout")
    )
}

logoutOfApps().done(logoutRedirect);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness thought I would document exactly how I changed it, which took a little while to get just right.  Thank you adeneo for your answer that I accepted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    onLoadOfPage();
}
</script>
```

This is in the second file (I preferred all jquery code in one file):

```
function onLoadOfPage(){
    $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
        logoutRedirect();
    });
    logoutOfApps().done(logoutRedirect);
}
function logoutOfApps(){
    return $.when(
        $.post("/app1/logout"),
        $.post("/app2/logout")
    )
}
function logoutRedirect(){
    var redirectOnLogoutURL = null;
    redirectOnLogoutURL = "/mylogoutdisplaypage";
    top.location = redirectOnLogoutURL;
}
```